# Android error on unused column

Tags: android, sqlite

I am building an app that creates and communicates with an SQLite database.

However, each time the app makes a connection with the database, it shuts down due to errors.

The (in my eyes) relevant errors are these:

```
03-21 07:50:29.308: E/AndroidRuntime(554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dummies.android.taskreminder/com.dummies.android.taskreminder.ReminderListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

03-21 07:50:29.308: E/AndroidRuntime(554): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

In the tutorial I used, the ID column is named "_id" but i renamed it to "ReminderID" before ever using it. The term "_id" is never used in my version and renaming the variable "ReminderID" to "_id" gives me the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database doesn't have to have a column called '_id' but the SimpleCursorAdaptor does need to have one returned. You can do this with an alias.
 _id field is used as a unique key to make sure the data the cursor handles can be handled correctly by adapters and adapterviews etc.
if

```
ReminderID,XYZ ABC are your columns... then
```

To query  for your SimpleCursorAdapter, you can  do this with a database rawQuery...

```
 SELECT  ReminderID as _id,XYZ,ABC FROM MY_TABLE
```

Comment: If I have a method for fetching a specific record and one for all records as following, how do I have to alter the query then?

public Cursor fetchAllReminders() {
 return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
 
public Cursor fetchReminder(long rowId) throws SQLException {
 Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_DATE_TIME}, KEY_ROWID + "=" +
 rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
 if (mCursor != null) {
  mCursor.moveToFirst();
 }
 return mCursor;
}

Comment: when using aliasing.. u can use like this..new String[] ={RemainderId,XYZ,ABC}...IS same as..String[] =             {RemainderId _id,XYZ,ABC}<--- see there is a space after remainer id.. and not a comma.. it takes it as "RemainderId as _id"

Answer (score 1):

_id is a convention on android, cursorAdapter needs it for instance.

Answer (score 0):

_id column is not that you table you can pot this column or other remove to _id key in you query